# Remove blue outline from NSSplitView's subviews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssplitview

I have an `NSSplitView`, and each subview (left/right) seems to draw a bright blue outline around them when clicked. Each of these subviews is a `NSScrollView`

Is there a means of disabling this? I have dug through the docs to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the Attributes inspector and under the "View" category set `Focus Ring` property to none.

[image]

Make sure you do this to all views in the view hierarchy.

Comment: This works great. Made an edit to show how to do it programmatically, since I am using RubyMotion and no IB.